# ImportError: cannot import name 'SECP256kl' from 'ecdsa'

Tags: python, ecdsa

I'm trying to use this code:

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey, SECP256kl
```

But I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SECP256kl' from 'ecdsa' (C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ecdsa\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct name is `SECP256k1` (the number "**1**", not the letters "**l**" or "**I**").

```
>>> import ecdsa
>>> dir(ecdsa)
[...,'SECP256k1',...]
```

You can also check it from the docs and codes in [ecdsa github page](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa):

```
 # python-ecdsa/src/ecdsa/__init__.py
...
from .curves import NIST192p, NIST224p, NIST256p, NIST384p, NIST521p, SECP256k1
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but even l is not the problem, I just Capitalize the S for sign and K for key and it works.

Comment: @cristinaparker Sorry I don't understand what you just said. The problem with your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55699933/1) is not `SigningKey` (that part is correct). The problem is that you used `SECP256kl` instead of `SECP256k1`.